# How can I evaluate the accuracy of a clustering when I don't have information on the true class labels?

Tags: clustering, k-means

Already classified data set for the t-shirt factory problem

I want to calculate the accuracy of my algorithm. I have the training data without any size information and I couldn't find the classified version of the data set. Should I create artificial data or find another data set?

Comment: Can you add more details about your situation?

Comment: I've implemented k-means algorithm according to height and weight attributes of each person. There is no size (class) information in the data set to compare the accuracy of my implementation by checking whether each data is in its correct class.

Comment: So is your question just: 'How can I evaluate the accuracy of a clustering when I don't have information on the true class labels?'

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I want to do.